# Where can I download old versions of the Adobe Flex SDK?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe

Now that the Flex SDK has migrated to Apache, I can't seem to find old versions of the Adobe Flex SDK. I'm maintaining a legacy project that will not compile with the latest Apache Flex SDK, and I cannot afford to spend time overhauling the whole project for some minor bug fixes. I'd prefer to continue using the same Adobe Flex SDK that the app was originally developed with. Where can I find old builds of the Adobe Flex SDK?

Comment: Unfortunately; questions asking for an off-site resource are off-topic on Stack Overflow...

Comment: That truly is unfortunate. In my opinion, this is the obvious place to go looking for this information, since Adobe doesn't seem to have a decent archive page for the Flex SDK on its help site like it does for Flash Player and AIR.

Comment: I would have expected most developers will use Google to find the old SDKs; and not come to StackOverflow directly for such a question.

Comment: The problem is that the Google results don't help much. I finally found the SDK URLs by downloading a weird SWF on blogs.adobe.com that I had top open in the standalone Flash Player. The developer I was helping said that they found the same SWF, but they couldn't get it to run for some reason. It was definitely non-trivial. If this StackOverflow question showed up in the top results on Google, it would make things easier for everyone.

Comment: Post the list on a blog or elsewhere in case it gets flagged for removal here.  The reason they want to avoid questions like this is that they become "non-helpful" when the links change.

Comment: That's kind of funny considering that I chose StackOverflow because the community can provide better answers long after I stop caring. On my blog, I'm probably the only person who can provide updated info. It seems like there's a better chance of a non-helpful info getting improved here. Oh well. I'll just duplicate it on my blog, I guess.

Comment: But the question isn't really "helpful" it is just a list of links.  For whatever reason this hasn't been hit by what many would call the "SO Nazis"; so maybe it'll stay.  Who knows!  Read through the help section if you haven't in a while: http://stackoverflow.com/tour Somewhere in there it talks about types of questions.

Comment: This whole discussion makes me regret being excited to contribute some time-consuming research to the community.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  You have the right attitude; just I think the wrong venue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following versions of the Adobe Flex SDK are available for download from Adobe:

- [4.6.0.23201B](https://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/flex/sdk/builds/flex4.6/flex_sdk_4.6.0.23201B.zip)
- [4.5.1.21328A](https://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/flex/sdk/builds/flex4.5/flex_sdk_4.5.1.21328A.zip)
- [4.5.0.20967A](https://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/flex/sdk/builds/flex4.5/flex_sdk_4.5.0.20967A.zip)
- [4.1.0.16076A](https://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/flex/sdk/builds/flex4/flex_sdk_4.1.0.16076A.zip)
- [4.0.0.14159A](https://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/flex/sdk/builds/flex4/flex_sdk_4.0.0.14159A.zip)
- [3.6.0.16995A](https://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/flex/sdk/builds/flex3/flex_sdk_3.6.0.16995A.zip)
- [3.5.0.12683B](https://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/flex/sdk/builds/flex3/flex_sdk_3.5.0.12683B.zip)
- [3.4.1.10084A](https://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/flex/sdk/builds/flex3/flex_sdk_3.4.1.10084A.zip)
- [3.3.0.4852A](https://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/flex/sdk/builds/flex3/flex_sdk_3.3.0.4852A.zip)
- [3.2.0.3958A](https://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/flex/sdk/builds/flex3/flex_sdk_3.2.0.3958A.zip)
- [3.1.0.2710A](https://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/flex/sdk/builds/flex3/flex_sdk_3.1.0.2710A.zip)
- [3.0.1.1732A](https://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/flex/sdk/builds/flex3/flex_sdk_3.0.1.1732A.zip)
- [3.0.0.477A](https://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/flex/sdk/builds/flex3/flex_sdk_3.0.0.477A.zip)

Comment: It appears these links no longer work.

Comment: @Vector I just gave the links a try, and they are still working for me.

Comment: how do you access them? Whenever I click on a link, it just momentarily indicates a page load and then nothing happens. If I try and open in new tab, the new tab just immediately closes right after opening.

Comment: @Vector If you click one of the links above, it won't go to another webpage first. It should start the download immediately. Maybe your web browser's settings are configured to automatically save downloaded files to your Downloads folder without asking where to save them first?

Comment: I'm very familiar with web based downloads. I develop web aps. I haven't pulled it up in the dev tools debugger to see what going wrong, but nothing is ever downloaded. So weird. I just used wget on linux and it pulled down just fine. I've done other web downloads with no issue. So weird. Thank you for your comments, they really helped!

Comment: It isn't downloading because it tries to open an HTTP link instead of HTTPS, copy the link address you are interested in and change the http:// to https:// and it should download.

Comment: Still works to change to https as of 221115